# multiple unique key in a multi index

Tags: algorithm, stl, boost-multi-index

I am trying to store objects in a `boost multi-index` container.

These objects are all unique can be retrieved by 2 separate keys (unique as well).

```
namepsace bm = boost::multi_index;

class MyObj {
 string  strid_;
 int32_t numid_;
};

//! associative container searchable by ClOrdId and Sunofia Id.  
typedef boost::multi_index_container< MyObj,
bm::indexed_by<
  bm::ordered_unique<
    bm::member<MyObj,string,&MyObj::strid_>
  >,
  bm::ordered_unique<
    bm::member<MyObj,int32,&MyObj::numid_>
  >
>            
> Cntr;
Cntr cntr_;
```

When I try to find any element of that index by integer I use the following code

```
 int32_t to_find = 12;
 Cntr::iterator it = cntr_.find(id);
```

but it doesn't compile and I get the following error

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’
```

When I use the same code with string it works fine; do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto it = cntr_.get<1>().find(id);
```

Each index is accessed separately (via `get`) and has its own member functions, iterators, etc. (In case you can't use `auto`,`it` is of type `Cntr::nth_index<1>::type::iterator`.) More info on the doc [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html).

Comment: Hi! Just noticed that you are the guy who created the lib!!!Ah! Good stuff indeed, tons of lines of code less to write! :)

Comment: Glad to know it's useful :-)